# Format money with negative number

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that works well with positive number but when input the negative number it alert `NaN`:

```
function formatMoney(number) {
        number = parseFloat(number.toString().match(/^\d+\.?\d{0,2}/));
        //Seperates the components of the number
        var components = (Math.floor(number * 100) / 100).toString().split(".");
        //Comma-fies the first part
        components [0] = components [0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        //Combines the two sections
        return components.join(".");
    }
alert(formatMoney(-11));
```

Here is the example in jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/longvu/wRYsU/

thanks for any help

Comment: What do you think `.match(/^\d+\.?\d{0,2}/))` does?

Comment: If *match* does not find a match, it returns `null`, and `parseFloat(null)` returns `NaN`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no allowance for a leading sign in `/^\d+\.?\d{0,2}/`, it *must* start with a digit.

First step is to allow for that, with something like:

```
/^-?\d+\.?\d{0,2}/
```

If you place *that* in your example jsfiddle script, you get a dialog box with `-11` rather than `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you can get rid of the first regular expression (unless you want to validate input) and use:

```
function formatAsMoney(n) {
  n = (Number(n).toFixed(2) + '').split('.');
  return n[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + '.' + (n[1] || '00');
}
```

There were once issues with *toFixed*, but I don't think it's a problem any more.